# Should I declare the interface as the return value or the implementation as the return value?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

Which of the following is correct when writing a method that returns an arrayList of cats.

```
public List getCatsByCatHerderID(int id);

public ArrayList<Cat> getCatsByCatHerderID(int id);

public List<Cat> getCatsByCatHerderID(int id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I was looking for something that described all of those but didn't tag it a million times. That was it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List<Cat>` is the best choice. Firstly, it declares an interface as a return value, so you can modify the implementation later, for example switch from an ArrayList to something else. Secondly, it uses generics, which is always better, as it makes the value typesafe.

Answer (score 2):

The third one.

The first is bad since it'll force the user of your API to cast List entries, and he may choose to cast them to (Dog) for all you now.

The second is bad cause what if Java comes up with SuperFastList in 1.7, and you want to use that instead of ArrayList?

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<Cat> getCatsByCatHerderID(int id);
```

The 3rd method, as you only deal with methods defined in list and never to worry of what type of list is returned by the method. Also, if you are going to use Web Services, the 3rd method is ok, as `List` is better understood in Web Services than `ArrayList` (imagine .NET having `ArrayList`?)

If you **really** want to return `ArrayList`, then this:

```
public ArrayList<Cat> getCatsByCatHerderID(int id);
```